# Understanding Two's Complements

Tags: binary, decimal, twos-complement

So from my understanding thus far, the 0 and 1 serve as the plus or minus sign in the number. If I have a number such as 10101 in binary (21 in decimal), how is this converted to negative? Does it become 10101 + 00001 = 10111? Or is it added to the front?

Also in attempting to understand it, what if you are trying to get a number in, say, nine-bit two's complements? Would writing this in nine-bits be 000010101 for 21 and then adding a one to the front?

I've gone back and forth but am failing to understand.

Comment: In 2's compliment MSB is not a sign bit

Answer (score 0):

To invert the sign of a two's complement number, you invert its bits and add one. The number of bits doesn't really matter. "Adding one" means to literally perform addition, not to append a 1 to the number or swap a 0 with a 1.

So for number 21 with nine bits:

```
21       = 000010101;
inverted = 111101010;
plus 1   = 111101011;
```

For 22 with nine bits:

```
22       = 000010110;
inverted = 111101001;
plus 1   = 111101010;
```

Answer (score 0):

I always picture two's complements as an odometer. If the (4digit) odometer is at 0000 and you run your car backwards for one km, then the odometer will show 9999. So 9999 repesents 1km backwards, or -1 km.

If you add 1km to this number you get 10000. But since you only have four digits, you end up with 0000. So -1km + 1km indeed results in 0km.

You sill need a way to distinguish whether 9999 is 9999 km forwards or 1 km backwards. This is merely a matter of convention. You can say that everything which starts with a 5 or higher is considered a negative distance. It does not matter much for computations, because 9999 + 0001 = 0000 no matter if 9999 came from 9999 km forwards or 1km backwards. It does however matter when you want to display 9999 as -1km.

The two's complement is the same idea for binary numbers.